# how can i get username when he/she signup in django?

Tags: python, django

i want the username when the user signUp

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
  form_class = UserCreationForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
  template_name = 'signup.html'
```

i need to access the username of the user who has been signed up .

Comment: Where do you need to access it? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: i need to access it in Class SignUp , and i want to create a file using the username @DanielRoseman

Comment: That didn't explain anything at all. What file? Where? Where do you want to access it in the class? Show some code that demonstrates what you want to do.

Comment: i need to create a json file and name of the file i need is the user name. That is why i need to get the username of the user who is signing up in the code below.  `class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
  form_class = UserCreationForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
  template_name = 'signup.html'` @DanielRoseman

Comment: But, do you need the username in the UserCreationForm or in the SignUp View? Write the code where you want to use the username

Comment: i need to get the username in SignUp View. can u please tell me the code to get user name in SignUp View. @grouchoboy

Comment: i need to get the username in SignUp View. can u please tell me the code to get user name in SignUp View. @grouchoboy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the post data with `request.POST`. You can override the `post` request of
the `CreateView` and add the specific code to do what you want with the username and then continue with the default flow of the [`CreateView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6275b50ac26ea6c026aa7b2aae9192f5792e8a94/django/views/generic/edit.py#L170) `post` method/

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    # do something with the username
    # and continue
    self.object = None
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you need to use the user after it has been stored in the database you could modify the `create` method of the serializer instead of modifying the `post`.

```
class UserCreationForm:
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        username = user.username
        # do something with the username or the user
        return user
```

Comment: this is working but user is not created in database. is there any solution

Comment: You can modify the serializer and call the code after the user has been created.